# vector<bool> no viable overloaded '='

Tags: c++

In this snippet,

```
void Graph::dfs(int s) const {
    m_Marked[s] = true;
    // ...
}
```

where `std::vector<bool> m_Marked;`

I see from compiler,

```
../Algorithms/graph.cpp:54:17: error: no viable overloaded '='
    m_Marked[s] = true;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:155:28: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'bool' to 'const std::__1::__bit_const_reference<std::__1::vector<bool, std::__1::allocator<bool> > >' for 1st argument
    __bit_const_reference& operator=(const __bit_const_reference& __x);
```

Absolutely no idea what his problem is, this seems pretty basic?

TIA

Comment: Remove `const` from object method.
Alternatively, but not recommended, declare `m_Marked` as `mutable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined your function as const, so you promised not to change anything.  An assignment operation is changing something, and a violation of that promise.